Controlling the length of stream lines in StreamPlot3D
We need to control the length of stream lines to a desirable limit in a StreamPlot3D, without explicitly depending on coordinates range. While using the StreamPlot3D, the length of the stream lines are automatic. How to decrease or increase the length of stream lines without explicitly depending on coordinates range?
Using StreamPlot3D we get the first figure, using the code:
Show[StreamPlot3D[{Cos[z] - Cos[y], Cos[x] - Cos[z], 
   Cos[y] - Sin[x]}, {x, -10, 25}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  StreamPoints -> {{1, 1, 1}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}],
 Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, .82]}]]

But we need to obtain the length reduced figure as given in figure 2.
Thank you for your support.



How the second image was produced?

It was generated from the code available in: https://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/fieldLines3D.html

point is the point of interest - stream line spreads of this point to both directions.
len is length of the stream line, must be positive integer.
Remark - it is not clear to me why StreamPlot3D produces 3 lines when it was explicitly given that it should be one specific line that goes through point StreamPoints -> {{1, 1, 1}}. Therefore determining the correct line and deleting others was necessary.
point = {1, 1, 1};
len = 110;

strp = StreamPlot3D[{Cos[z] - Cos[y], Cos[x] - Cos[z], 
    Cos[y] - Sin[x]}, {x, -10, 25}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
   StreamPoints -> {point}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}];

lines = Cases[strp, x_Line, All];

nrst = First@Nearest[#, point] & /@ lines[[All, 1]];

po = Position[nrst, x_List /; EuclideanDistance[x, point] < 0.01][[1, 
    1]];

poz = Position[lines[[po, 1]], 
    Nearest[lines[[po, 1]], point][[1]]][[1, 1]];

lline = Length[lines[[po, 1]]];

newplot = 
  strp /. (# -> {} & /@ 
        lines[[DeleteCases[Range[Length@lines], po]]]) /. 
     x_Line :> 
      Line[lines[[po, 1]][[#]], 
       VertexColors -> lines[[po, 2, 2]][[#]]] &@(Max[poz - len, 1] ;;
      Min[poz + len, lline]);

Show[newplot, Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[point, .5]}]]



I was able to reproduce your second image this way:


A shortened version is appreciated. Actually only one line is there, but the same line is going out of the boundary and re-entering in to the boundary, make the feel of more stream lines. This can be visualized by increasing the coordinate ranges. So this portion may be disregarded. In the above code line part specification is not working showing that "Part specification line[[1]] is longer than depth of object."

@SPJ I corrected the code, should work now. I do not have shorter code. Yes you are right about that it is a single stream line but divided into three lines. Even if it is so, we still have to choose the correct line.
